# OCaml: Functor application in type declaration

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to parametrise a functor using a type parameter in a declaration. As an example, suppose I have the following GADT declaration:

```
type _ basic = 
| String : string -> string basic
| Integer : int -> int basic
```

I want to use `Map.Make` to construct maps using the above type as the key type. Since I cannot leave a type variable free in `type t = 'a basic`, I have a functor to make `'a basic` into an `OrderedType`:

```
module OrderedBasic(Type : sig type tag end) : 
  (Map.OrderedType with type t = Type.tag basic) = 
struct
  type t = Type.tag basic

  let compare : type a. a basic -> a basic -> int = fun b1 b2 ->
    match b1, b2 with
    | String s1, String s2 -> String.compare s1 s2
    | Integer i1, Integer i2 -> compare i1 i2

end
```

I can create the maps I wanted:

```
module OrderedBasicString = OrderedBasic(struct type tag = string end)

module BasicStringMap = Map.Make(OrderedBasicString)
```

and name the map type:

```
type 'v string_map = 'v BasicStringMap.t
```

However, what I would like to do is to parametrise the type of maps by the type parameter of `basic`, i.e., something like:

```
type ('k, 'v) basic_map = 'v Map.Make(OrderedBasic(struct type tag = 'k end)).t
```

But this doesn't seem to be allowed: I get a syntax error at the inline `struct` definition. Ultimately, I want to embed maps, which can have any of the above basic key types, in another GADT as in:

```
type _ data = 
  Map : 'a data Map.Make(OrderedBasic(struct type tag = 'b end)).t -> 'c data
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Map` is defined over key types of fixed arity, and that arity is zero.

It's easy if the functor you are using allows the arity you want:

```
type _ basic =
  | String : string -> string basic
  | Integer : int -> int basic

module type INDEXED = sig
  type 'a t
  val equal : 'a t -> 'a t -> bool
end

module MakeAlist (Elt : INDEXED) = struct
  type ('i, 'v) t = Nil | Cons of 'i Elt.t * 'v * ('i, 'v) t

  let rec find elt = function
    | Nil -> None
    | Cons (x, v, xs) ->
      if Elt.equal elt x then Some v
      else find elt xs

  (* etc *)
end

module BasicAlist = MakeAlist (struct
    type 'a t = 'a basic
    let equal : type a . a basic -> a basic -> bool = fun b1 b2 ->
      match b1, b2 with
      | String s1, String s2 -> s1 = s2
      | Integer i1, Integer i2 -> i1 = i2
  end)

type _ data = Map : ('a data, 'b) BasicAlist.t -> 'c data
```

I won't go as far as suggesting that you reimplement `Map` with the arity that you want, although that would solve your problem - there might be some trick I'm not aware of that would let you reuse `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a map that is polymorphic in the type of the key such as the [map from core](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel.112.17.00/_build/lib/core_map/).

```
open Core.Std

module Basic = struct
    type 'a t =
      | String : string -> string t
      | Int : int -> int t

    let sexp_of_t : type a. a t -> Sexp.t = function
      | String s -> String.sexp_of_t s
      | Int i -> Int.sexp_of_t i

    let compare : type a. a t -> a t -> int = fun b1 b2 ->
      match b1, b2 with
      | String s1, String s2 -> String.compare s1 s2
      | Int i1, Int i2 -> compare i1 i2
  end

module Cmp = Comparator.Make1(Basic)

type _ data =
  Map : ('a Basic.t, 'b, Cmp.comparator_witness) Map.t -> 'c data
```